# How to generate API Documentation using openapi-generator?

Tags: yaml, openapi, openapi-generator, api-doc

I'm new to the `OpenAPI` 3.0.0.

I have successfully created a java client library using an **openapi-generator**.

But `OpenAPI` Generator allows the generation of API client libraries (SDK generation), server stubs, documentation. So I want to know is there any commands or steps are available to generate HTML documentation and also to customize the documentation template.

Comment: Are you talking about Swagger documentation ? Open api document itself is used by Swagger UI or Redoc.

Comment: Yes. My use case is the openapi-generator has to create an API documentation in HTML. So that I can host that file in our web application. Is that possible ?

Comment: Definitely just google for 'open api tool chain for xyz'. There are toolchain that will be integrated with your code to host UI. If you want to customize the same , you can download UI source e.g. SwaggerUI , and integrate into your toolchain

Answer (score 25):

Old question, but for those still bumping into it.  OpenApi Generator can do generation of html documentation from your yaml or json definition of your API.

```
openapi-generator generate -i PathToMyInputDefinitionFile.yaml -g html -o /PathToOutputFolder
```

Where `html` is the generator you want to use.  Other generators include `dynamic-html` and `html2`.  Also can emit as markdown.  See https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/

If using Docker, a full example would look like this:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator:tagname generate -i /local/input.yaml -g html -o /local
```

PWD is present working directory (current directory) in the host, which you are mapping on to /local in the container.  Adjust 'tagname' to suit, from https://hub.docker.com/r/openapitools/openapi-generator/tags  Adjust `input.yaml` to be your input file yaml definition of your API.

Comment: Do you know if openapi-generator can be used programmatically ? That is, from Java to read an input.yml and produce the html2 pages?

Comment: The command was changed to `openapi-generator-cli`.